# How long does it take to renew an Iraqi passport from the US Iraqi embassy?

Tags: passports, passport-renewals, iraqi-citizens

I am not sure if this is the correct forum, but could anyone please tell me what is the estimate time to renew Iraqi passport from a foreign embassy. I am planning to do it through the US Iraqi embassy.

Comment: Looking at the embassy website (using machine translation, since I do not read Arabic), it appears as though the consular section of the embassy only issues emergency passports, but that you might be able to get a regular passport at the consulate in Detroit or Los Angeles.  I couldn't load their websites, however, so I couldn't see what they have to say about it.